# Issue with changing data type in Strapi collection type

Tags: strapi

I'm new to Strapi, and I have just created a couple of collections types, one of them has a field named `description` set to `Long text`.

I'd like to change the data type from `Long text` to `Rich text`, is there a way to edit the data type on this field, or do I need to delete and recreate it with the new data type?

Answer (score 3):

you need to delete and re-create the data type. if you create it by giving the same name, then you will not lose data because your database will keep the field without deleting it.

Comment: Actually I could edit the datatype on my backend strapi code, and then refresh the strapi admin page.
And as I changed from one text datatype to another, it didnt cause any issues :)

Comment: Doing so gave me an error: ApplicationError: Could not find field size for type rich text And it deleted all the content which was in the description field. Recreating the field worked and I did not loose any data.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the content type schema.json on the code and change the type in the attribute.
No need to delete.

```js
"description":{
"type":"rich text"
}
```

Comment: Doing so gave me an error: `ApplicationError: Could not find field size for type rich text` And it deleted all the content which was in the description field